# How to start 2 (or more) instances of Rocket.Chat using Docker Compose?

Tags: nginx, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, rocket.chat

I'm developing some projects that are available under the same Amazon EC2 instance (AWS EC2 instance) and I'm trying to create a [Rocket.Chat](https://rocket.chat) for each of these projects. Note that each of these projects has it's own userbase and is *completely* isolated from others, thus each Rocket.Chat instance should be isolated too.

What I want to do is somewhat like the following:

- `www.example1.com` has it's chat at `chat.example1.com`;
- `www.example2.com` has it's chat at `chat.example2.com`;
- And so on...

Remember that `www.example1.com`, `www.example2.com` (...) are hosted in the same EC2 instance. This instance has a Nginx server that serves these sites. So you can imagine that I have the following architecture:

```
# Sites content
  /var/www/www.example1.com/
     index.php
     (...)

  /var/www/www.example2.com/
     index.php
     (...)

# Chats content
  /var/www/chat.example1.com/
    data/
    docker-compose.yml
    (...)

  /var/www/chat.example2.com/
    data/
    docker-compose.yml
    (...)

# Nginx config
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www_example1_com
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www_example2_com
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/chat_example1_com
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/chat_example2_com
```

Everythings was going fine while I have a single Rocket.Chat instance using Docker Compose, but with more instances things get confused. I'm **trying** to attach the following ports to each instance:

```
chat.example1.com
    db: 27017
    rocketchat: 3000
    hubot: 3001

chat.example2.com
    db: 27017
    rocketchat: 3002
    hubot: 3003
```

The things get weird when `chat.example1.com` works as expected, but `chat.example2.com` no. I've found that `chat.example2.com` is being initialized in port 3000 according to it's own output, therefore change the property `ports` in the docker-compose.yml file doesn't seems to be working. Did I misunderstood some key concepts from Docker Compose or it's really not working as expected?

If I try to access the sites, I got the following:

- `chat.example1.com` -> works as expected.
- `chat.example1.com:3000` -> "Secure connection failed".
- `chat.example1.com:3002` -> Page never loads.
- `chat.example2.com` -> Nginx shows up `www.example2.com`.
- `chat.example2.com:3000` -> Loads, but seems to be using chat.example1.com Rocket.Chat instance / database.
- `chat.example2.com:3002` -> Page never loads.

What's going on? What should I do in order to fix these problems and get as many Rocket.Chat instances as I want, each of them being provided in the URL I want? There's no problem in using ports explicitly to access chats (e.g: use `chat.example2.com:3002` instead `chat.example2.com`, but the later is more desirable).

---

**Below you can see the most relevant files.**

*Note: for didactic and privacy reasons I've changed everything to use chat.example1.com and chat.example2.com, hope you don't get it wrong. If things get confused to you, tell me so I check if there's a mistake, typo or give more info. Also, feel free to suggest a better approach for this problem.*

### /var/www/chat.example1.com/docker-compose.yml

```
db:
  image: mongo
  volumes:
    - ./data/runtime/db:/data/db
    - ./data/dump:/dump
  command: mongod --smallfiles

rocketchat:
  image: rocketchat/rocket.chat:latest
  environment:
    - MONGO_URL=mongodb://db:27017/rocketchat
    - ROOT_URL=https://chat.example1.com/
    - Accounts_UseDNSDomainCheck=True
  links:
    - db:db
  ports:
    - 3000:3000

hubot:
  image: rocketchat/hubot-rocketchat:v0.1.4
  environment:
    - ROCKETCHAT_URL=chat.example1.com
    - ROCKETCHAT_ROOM=GENERAL
    - ROCKETCHAT_USER=Botname
    - ROCKETCHAT_PASSWORD=BotPassw0rd
    - BOT_NAME=Botname
    - EXTERNAL_SCRIPTS=hubot-help,hubot-seen,hubot-links,hubot-greetings
  links:
    - rocketchat:rocketchat
# this is used to expose the hubot port for notifications on the host on port 3001, e.g. for hubot-jenkins-notifier
  ports:
    - 3001:8080
```

### /var/www/chat.example2.com/docker-compose.yml

```
db:
  image: mongo
  volumes:
    - ./data/runtime/db:/data/db
    - ./data/dump:/dump
  command: mongod --smallfiles

rocketchat:
  image: rocketchat/rocket.chat:latest
  environment:
    - MONGO_URL=mongodb://db:27017/rocketchat
    - ROOT_URL=http://chat.example2.com/
    - Accounts_UseDNSDomainCheck=True
  links:
    - db:db
  ports:
    - 3002:3002

hubot:
  image: rocketchat/hubot-rocketchat:v0.1.4
  environment:
    - ROCKETCHAT_URL=chat.example2.com
    - ROCKETCHAT_ROOM=GENERAL
    - ROCKETCHAT_USER=Botname
    - ROCKETCHAT_PASSWORD=BotPassw0rd
    - BOT_NAME=Botname
    - EXTERNAL_SCRIPTS=hubot-help,hubot-seen,hubot-links,hubot-greetings
  links:
    - rocketchat:rocketchat
# this is used to expose the hubot port for notifications on the host on port 3001, e.g. for hubot-jenkins-notifier
  ports:
    - 3003:8080
```

### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/chat_example1_com:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen 80;
  server_name chat.example1.com;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/rocketchat_chat_example2_com_error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://chat.example1.com:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/chat_example2_com:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen 80;
  server_name chat.example2.com;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/rocketchat_chat_example2_com_error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://chat.example2.com:3002/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

### Docker ps

```
[ec2-user@ ~]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
2aa6bc690f0d        rocketchat/hubot-rocketchat:v0.1.4   "/bin/sh -c 'node -e "   16 hours ago        Up 16 hours         0.0.0.0:3003->8080/tcp             chatexample2com_hubot_1
eca85553211a        rocketchat/rocket.chat:latest        "node main.js"           16 hours ago        Up 16 hours         3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3002->3002/tcp   chatexample2com_rocketchat_1
5a0f5fda3b84        rocketchat/hubot-rocketchat:v0.1.4   "/bin/sh -c 'node -e "   17 hours ago        Up 17 hours         0.0.0.0:3001->8080/tcp             chatexample1com_hubot_1
a07149fd0e6e        rocketchat/rocket.chat:latest        "node main.js"           17 hours ago        Up 17 hours         0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp             chatexample1com_rocketchat_1
7ca3b1c3743f        mongo                                "/entrypoint.sh mongo"   18 hours ago        Up 17 hours         27017/tcp                          chatexample1com_db_1
f94d24c55b64        mongo                                "/entrypoint.sh mongo"   18 hours ago        Up 16 hours         27017/tcp                          chatexample2com_db_1
```

### chat.example2.com init

```
rocketchat_1  | ➔ System ➔ startup
rocketchat_1  | ➔ +-------------------------------------------------+
rocketchat_1  | ➔ |                  SERVER RUNNING                 |
rocketchat_1  | ➔ +-------------------------------------------------+
rocketchat_1  | ➔ |                                                 |
rocketchat_1  | ➔ |       Version: 0.37.1                           |
rocketchat_1  | ➔ |  Process Port: 3000                             |
rocketchat_1  | ➔ |      Site URL: http://chat.example2.com:3000    |
rocketchat_1  | ➔ |                                                 |
rocketchat_1  | ➔ +-------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Rocket.Chat on Docker always runs on port `3000`. So you need to change the file `/var/www/chat.example2.com/docker-compose.yml` in order to bind the host port `3002` to container port `3000`, like this:

```
...
rocketchat:
  image: rocketchat/rocket.chat:latest
  environment:
    - MONGO_URL=mongodb://db:27017/rocketchat
    - ROOT_URL=http://chat.example2.com/
    - Accounts_UseDNSDomainCheck=True
  links:
    - db:db
  ports:
    - 3002:3000
...
```